# How to get current milliseconds on flex application fast? Especially when SWF runs in browser on Mac or Linux

Tags: performance, macos, browser

We have a simple flex game.

And I want to keep my FPS constantly.

Now I use:

(new Date()).getTime();

It's OK in windows and it's OK in flashplayer on Mac and Linux.

But in browsers in Mac and Linux this method is too slow.
What can I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

use getTimer()
More info at:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#getTimer%28%29